# Find a general solution for $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin\left(x^n\right)\:dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

So, I was recently working on the Sine Fresnal integral and was curious whether we could generalise for any Real Number, i.e.

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin\left(x^n\right)\:dx$$

I have formed a solution that I'm uncomfortable with and was hoping for qualified eyes to have a look over.

So, the approach I took was to employ Complex Numbers (I forget the name(s) of the theorem that allows this).

But

$$\sin\left(x^n\right) = \Im\left[-e^{-ix^n}\right]$$

And so, n

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin\left(x^n\right)\:dx = \Im\left[\int_{0}^{\infty} -e^{-ix^n}\:dx \right]= -\Im\left[\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(i^{\frac{1}{n}}x\right)^{n}}\:dx \right]$$

Applying a change of variable $u = i^{\frac{1}{n}}x$ we arrive at:

\begin{align}
I &= -\Im\left[i^{-\frac{1}{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u^{n}}\:du \right] \\
  &= -\Im\left[i^{-\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n} \right]\\
  &= \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}
\end{align}

My area of concern is in the substitution. As $i^{-\frac{1}{n}} \in \mathbb{C}$, I believe the limits of the integral should have been from $0$ to $i^{-\frac{1}{n}}\infty$. Is that correct or not?

I'm also struggling with bounds on $n$ for convergence. Is this expression valid for all $n\in\mathbb{R}$

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where does the negative sign in the imaginary part come from

Comment: @Manthanein - I wanted the integral to take the form of the Gamma Function and so to get the negative part in the exponential, I used the property that $e^{-ix} = \cos(x) -sin(x)i$ or $-e^{ix} =-\cos(x) + \sin(x)$

Comment: @Manthanein - I just realised I hadn't used that form in the question. Have now corrected. Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: You have indeed moved the contour, so you need to show that the integral from $\infty$ to $i^{-1/n} \infty$ is zero, by an appropriate limiting argument.

Comment: @RichardMartin - Is my result then a consequence of bad maths giving the right answer or is there a link that I'm unaware of?

Comment: AFAIK it's that you've missed out a step that turned out not to make a difference. Try integrating from $L$ to $i^{-1/n}L$ in some arc or other, estimate the magnitude of the integrand (which probably goes to zero fast  because of the exponential) and then make $L$ large

Comment: @RichardMartin where I am left is whether that with $x$ originally going from $0$ to $\infty$ that means that through the $u$ substitution that means both the Real and Imaginary components are both going to $\infty$ or is it just the Real component? and if not, why can we equate the Imaginary component to be effectively if not definitively zero??

Yes it approaches $0$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$ but....

Comment: It's correct what you've done! You are integrating with $u:=i^{\frac{1}{n}}x$ from $0$ to $\infty$ . You are *not* integrating from $0$ to $i^{-\frac{1}{n}}\infty$ because you've extracted $i^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ .

Comment: @user90369 - Sorry I'm still lost, if I convert the integral from $x$ to $u$ using the substitution how is it not from $0$ to $i^{-\frac{1}{n}}\infty$ ?

This seems like a standard transformation. Why is it that the $i^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ doesn't become part of the limits?

Comment: Your integration is by $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$ . Then you change the integration variable $x$ to $i^{1/n}x$ which is substituted by $u$ . You are *not* changing the integration limits. Only if you still use $x$ as the integration variable, *then* you have the integration from $i^{1/n}0$ to $i^{1/n}\infty$ . E.g.: $\int_0^1 (2x)^n d(2x) = \int_0^1 u^n du$ but $\int_0^1 (2x)^n d(2x) = \int_0^2 x^n dx$

Comment: @DavidG : You know know, why you've calculated correctly ? :)

Comment: Do you think you could make some edits to improve the legibility of the fractions and exponents?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor - if that was addressed at myself then please advise how you would change the current layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach substitutes $y=x^n$ and writes $y^{1/n-1}$ in terms of a Gamma integral, viz. $$I=\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{n}y^{1/n-1}\exp(iy) dy=\Im\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{n\Gamma(1/n)}z^{-1/n}\exp(-y(z-i))dydz.$$By Fubini's theorem, and using $\Im\frac{1}{z-i}=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$,$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{n\Gamma(1/n)}\frac{z^{-1/n}}{1+z^2}dz.$$Then the substitution $z=\tan u$ obtains a Beta integral, which can be rewritten in terms of Gamma functions, and the result you've claimed is proven true, by the reflection formula of the Gamma function. Alternatively, we can a keyhole contour, as when proving the reflection formula; this doesn't use the above substitution, but benefits from another: $v=z^2$.

Answer (score 9):

Some Hints:

$$I=\int_0^{\infty} \sin (x^n)dx $$
On substitution $x^n=t$ and using the series of $\sin$  we get $$I=\frac 1n \int_0^{\infty} t^{\frac 1n} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac {t^{2k}k!}{(2k+1)!k!} \right) dt$$

On substituting $t^2=u$ we get $$ I= \frac {1}{2n} \int_0^{\infty} u^{\frac {1-n}{2n}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {\frac {k!}{(2k+1)!}}{k!} (-u)^k \right) du$$

Now by [*Ramanujan's Master Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem)

$$I=\frac {1}{2n} \Gamma(s)\phi(-s)$$ where $\phi(k)=\frac {k!}{(2k+1)!}$ and $s=\frac {n+1}{2n}$

Hence along with properties of [*Gamma function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), Mellin Transform and the Euler's reflection formula we get $$I=\frac {\pi}{2n\cos \left(\frac {\pi}{2n}\right)\Gamma \left(1-\frac 1n\right)}=\sin \left(\frac {\pi}{2n}\right)\frac {\Gamma\left(\frac 1n\right)}{n}$$

With a special case of $n=2$ we get the value of special integral popularly known as [*Fresnel integral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) with limit as $x$ tends to infinity

Answer (score 3):

Start out with a couple of integration by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\sin(x)\,e^{-xy}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\frac1y\int_0^\infty\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}e^{-xy}\tag1\\
&=\frac1y\int_0^\infty\cos(x)\,e^{-xy}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=-\frac1{y^2}\int_0^\infty\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}e^{-xy}\tag3\\
&=\frac1{y^2}-\frac1{y^2}\int_0^\infty\sin(x)\,e^{-xy}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag4\\
&=\frac1{y^2+1}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: prepare to integrate by parts
$(2)$: integrate by parts
$(3)$: prepare to integrate by parts
$(4)$: integrate by parts
$(5)$: add $\frac{y^2}{y^2+1}$ times $(4)$ to $\frac1{y^2+1}$ times the LHS of $(1)$

Now write 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\sin\left(x^n\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1n\int_0^\infty\sin(x)\,x^{\frac1n-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag6\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{n\,\Gamma\!\left(1-\frac1n\right)}\int_0^\infty\sin(x)\int_0^\infty y^{-\frac1n}e^{-xy}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x\tag7\\
&=\frac1{n\,\Gamma\!\left(1-\frac1n\right)}\int_0^\infty y^{-\frac1n}\int_0^\infty\sin(x)\,e^{-xy}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\tag8\\
&=\frac1{n\,\color{#C00}{\Gamma\!\left(1-\frac1n\right)}}\color{#090}{\int_0^\infty\frac{y^{-\frac1n}}{y^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}y}\tag9\\
&=\color{#C00}{\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac1n\right)\sin(\frac\pi{n})}{\color{#000}{n}\pi}}\color{#090}{\frac\pi2\sec\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right)}\tag{10}\\[9pt]
&=\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1n\right)\sin\left(\frac\pi{2n}\right)\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\phantom{1}(6)$: substitute $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$
$\phantom{1}(7)$: $\int_0^\infty y^{-\frac1n}e^{-xy}\,\mathrm{d}y=x^{\frac1n-1}\Gamma\!\left(1-\frac1n\right)$
$\phantom{1}(8)$: Fubini
$\phantom{1}(9)$: apply $(5)$
$(10)$: $(4)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216) for the green, and $(2)$ from the same answer for the red
$(11)$: simplify

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach that avoids complex numbers and series altogether. To get round these two obstacles I will use a property of the Laplace transform.

Let
$$I = \int_0^\infty \sin (x^n) \, dx, \qquad n > 1.$$
We begin by enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto x^{1/n}$. This gives
$$I = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^{1 - 1/n}} \, dx.$$

The following [useful property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) (does this result have a name? It would be so much nicer if it did!) for the Laplace transform will be used:
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty \mathcal{L} \{f(x)\} (t) \cdot \mathcal{L}^{-1} \{g(x)\} (t) \, dt.$$
Noting that
$$\mathcal{L} \{\sin x\}(t) = \frac{1}{1 + t^2},$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{\frac{1}{x^{1-1/n}} \right \} (t)= \frac{1}{\Gamma (1 - \frac{1}{n})} \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{\frac{\Gamma (1 - \frac{1}{n})}{x^{1-1/n}} \right \} (t) = \frac{t^{-1/n}}{\Gamma (1 - \frac{1}{n})},$$
then
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \sin x \cdot \frac{1}{x^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \mathcal{L} \{\sin x\} (t) \cdot \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{\frac{1}{x^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}} \right \} (t) \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{n\Gamma (1 - \frac{1}{n})} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{-1/n}}{1 + t^2} \, dt.
\end{align}
Enforcing a substitution of $t \mapsto \sqrt{t}$ yields
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2 n \Gamma \left (1 - \frac{1}{n} \right )} \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{-\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n}}}{t + 1} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2 n \Gamma \left (1 - \frac{1}{n} \right )} \operatorname{B} \left (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n}, \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n} \right )\\
&= \frac{1}{2 n \Gamma \left (1 - \frac{1}{n} \right )} \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n} \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n} \right ). \tag1
\end{align}
Applying Euler's reflexion formula we have
$$\Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n} \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n} \right ) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \left (\frac{\pi}{2n} + \frac{\pi}{2} \right )} = \frac{\pi}{\cos \left (\frac{\pi}{2n} \right )},$$
and
$$\Gamma \left (1 - \frac{1}{n} \right ) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \left (\frac{\pi}{n} \right ) \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{n} \right )}.$$
So (1) becomes
$$I = \frac{\sin (\frac{\pi}{n} ) \Gamma (\frac{1}{n})}{2n \cos (\frac{\pi}{2n} )},$$
or
$$I = \sin \left (\frac{\pi}{2n} \right ) \frac{\Gamma \left (\frac{1}{n} \right )}{n}, \qquad n > 1$$
where in the last line the double angle formula for sine has been used.