# Finding the integral $\int_0^\infty\sin(x^n)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Is there a non-complex number involving method to find the following integral

> $$\int_0^\infty\sin(x^n)dx$$

Maybe something using the idea similar to that for evaluating $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ under the same limits.
I have no idea about contours and I am hoping that there should be another real method to evaluate it.

Comment: WA says this here $$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{2 n}\right) \Gamma
   \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right),\Re(n)>1\land
   \Im(n)=0\right]$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner that is where my friend found this integral

Comment: I can get this simply with contour integration, but I have tried a couple of real only approaches that have not gotten anywhere. If you want a complex analysis approach, i can supply one.

Comment: @robjohn any solution which involves complex numbers is fine as long as it is limited to $cis(\theta\)$ no contours please

Comment: @SayamSethi: Since your question is closed, I wrote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3118441). It is totally real, no complex analysis (the reflection formula and the Beta function proof cited uses contour integration, but those are well-known and there are real proofs of them).

Comment: @robjohn thanks a lot

Comment: @SayamSethi: I have added a non-contour integration proof of the Beta function (and therefore, the reflection formula).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C=\int_0^\infty\cos (x^n) dx,\,S=\int_0^\infty\sin (x^n) dx$ so$$C+iS=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^\infty y^{1/n-1}\exp (iy)dy\\=\frac{1}{n\Gamma(1/n)}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty z^{-1/n}\exp [-y(z-i)]dydz\\=\frac{1}{n\Gamma(1/n)}\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{-1/n}(z+i)dz}{z^2+1}.$$You can do the rest with Beta and Gamma functions. Just doing the sine-based integral as requested, the substitution $z=\tan t$ gives$$\frac{1}{n\Gamma(1/n)}\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{-1/n} (t)dt=\frac{\pi}{2n\Gamma(1/n)}\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right).$$For $n=2$, this reduces to a famous Fresnel integral.

Comment: Two things are not very clear to me.... What happened to the $y^(1/n-1)$ when you introduced gamma and how did you get the last integral value?

Comment: @SayamSethi For your first question, I used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization). The second part is a special case of $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2a-1}t\cos^{2b-1}tdt=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$ with $a+b=1$.

Comment: Ok... I missed that the second part is a beta function...however I am not sure I get the first part....I have just learnt the elementary integrals (I am still not in my undergrad), do you mind explaining a little more

Comment: @SayamYethi The definition $\Gamma(s):=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\exp -tdt$ implies $\Gamma(s)y^{-s}=\int_0^\infty z^{s-1}\exp -yzdz$ from the substitution $t=yz$.

Comment: Lack of parentheses make this hard to parse.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks; fixed.