# Prove to converges $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin x^2dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\sin x^2dx$$

My work:

Let $x^2=t$. Then $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin x^2dx=\int_0^{+\infty}t\sin tdt$

Is it correct? How I will can finish it?

[wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7D%5Csin%20x%5E2dx)

Comment: $dt =2xdx=2\sqrt t dx$ and $dx=\frac 1 {2\sqrt t} dt$.

Comment: Do you want to prove that converges only or calculate it also?

Comment: $$x^2=t\implies 2x\,dx=dt\implies dx=\frac 1{2\sqrt t}dt$$ Your substitution is incorrect

Comment: For explicit calculation  look at Fresnel integrals..You will need contour integration and complex analysis.

Comment: Is this integral convergent at all ? The function is extremely oscillating for large $x$.

Comment: @Peter The function oscillates more quickly with large $x$, but the oscillations of $\int_0^M \sin (x^2) \,dx$ become smaller as $M$ increases.

Comment: @Peter $sin(x^2)$ oscillates a lot, but that doesn't mean that the integral will. As x increases, the oscillations get narrower, but same amplitude, so the fluctuations in area get smaller.

Comment: Why not you use complex analysis to calculate the integral of $sin(x^2)$ from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: See here for a generalized version: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2991233/463895   which states the explicit value of the integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Fresnel integral. It equals to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$.

$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)dx = \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^2)dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)dx$.

The first integral is obviously bounded.

The second integral can be rewritten (as pointed out above in the comments) as

$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)dx = \left|\begin{array}{c} x^2 = t \Rightarrow 2xdx = dt \\ dx = \frac{dt}{2x} = \frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}}\end{array}\right| = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\sin(t)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}dt$.

The latter integral converges according to Dirichlet's test:

Let us consider the following integral $\int_a^{+\infty}f(t)g(t)dt$.

In our case,

- $a = 1$,
- $f(t) = \sin(t)$,
- $g(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}$.

1) If the integral of a function $f(t)$ is uniformly bounded over all intervals
within $[a, +\infty)$. (TRUE)

2) If $g(t)$ is a monotonically decreasing non-negative function. (TRUE)

Then the integral $\int_a^{+\infty}f(t)g(t)dt$ is a convergent improper integral.